# Java rewriting inherited methods

Tags: java, inheritance

So I naively wrote an abstract class (A game board) containing a field with no access modifier for an array used to store the game state (a Square[]). This class has various methods implemented using this Square[]. I also have two subclasses both inheriting from this class, using these same methods from their parent class.

Now, for one reason or another, I have to make my Square[] private. I thought a simple fix would be to make a getter method as usual,

```
Class Board {
...
    /**An array contain all the Squares for my board. */
    private Square[] squares;

    public Square[] getSquares() {
        return squares;
    }
}

class MutableBoard extends Board {

    /** An N x N board in initial configuration. */
    MutableBoard(int N) {
        _N = N;
        squares = new Square[_N * _N];
        for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
            squares[i] = new Square();
        }
    }

    @Override
    void copy(Board board) {
        _N = board.size();
        _moves = board.numMoves();
        squares = new Square[board.getSquares().length]; //Errors here when used
        for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
            squares[i] = board.squares[i].clone();
        }
    }
}

class ConstantBoard extends Board {

    /** A new ConstantBoard that allows a read-only view of BOARD. */
    ConstantBoard(Board board) {
        _board = board;
        squares = board.getSquares();
    }
}
```

but I keep getting null pointer exceptions every time I try to access or modify my array in my subclasses using inherited methods. I think because my Square[] is defined in my parent class, its trying to access Board's copy of the array, not the subclasses copy. Does anyone know an easy fix to this that doesn't involve just putting all my methods in both subclasses (and defeating the whole point of inheritance)?

For example, in my copy method, I want to be able to pass in both a MutableBoard, and Constant Board, but I think its trying to access a copy of Board's squares somehow, which isn't even initialized.

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't even compile - so you wouldn't be getting a NullPointerException... If you haven't posted your *actual* code, we can't help you with it.

Comment: Return type should be array of square " public Board[] getSquares() "

Comment: If you're getting a null pointer error, you could initialize the object on creation, otherwise it's just going to return squares containing null.

Comment: Right, now that you've fixed that - we've no idea where `squares` is being initialized. *Is* it being initialized? I suspect the problem has nothing to do with inheritance, and it's just a matter of a lack of initialization. If you were to post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, we'd be able to tell.

Comment: Do you even have a `Square` class?

Comment: Yes I have a square class. Sorry about the lack of info. I edited it to hopefully be more clear. It's been a long night.

Comment: Do you have `_N` and `_board` in your `Board` class?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception pointing to?

Answer (score 2):

You should return `Square[]`

```
public Square[] getSquares() {
    return squares;
}
```

`squares[]` is of type `Square`, therefore the method should return a `Square[]` not a `Board`

You also need to make sure you have `squares[]` initialized

```
private Square[] squares = new Square[someSize];

for (int i = 0; i < suqares.length; i++){
    squares[i] = new Square();
}
```

Also, you haven't delcared `_N` before trying to initialize it in you `MutableBoard`

```
 _N = N;

public class MutableBoard extends Board {
    int _N;

    public MutablerBoard(int N){
        _N = N;
    }
}

-or- 

public abstract class Board {
    int _N;
}

same for _board
```

Also, you should make `square[]` in your `Board` class `public static`. You can't modify it from `MutableBoard` if its `private` and you can't access the "current state" of `square` from `ConstantBoard` if it is not `static`.

Comment: Sorry yeah that was just my mistake typing the question. Edited.

Comment: I think it should be typo otherwise it wont compile.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't getSquares() should return squares?

```
public Square[] getSquares() {
        return squares;
 }
```

You declare that you want to return instance of Board class and you return array of Squares.

Comment: yeah just a typo. Edited.

Comment: Could you show some code where you actually create this array of Squares? Now when you create class Board your array is null because you didn't create it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean:

```
public Square[] getSquares() {
 return squares;
}
```

You have not initialised the array `squares`. 
You'll need:

```
Square[] squares = new Square[SIZE];
```

Even then, although the array will be initialised, each `Square` in the array will still be null. You'll need to initialsie them too:

```
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  squares[i] = new Square();  //or some other way of getting a `Square`
}
```

Above, SIZE is some `static final int` indicating the number of squares.

EDIT:

Your `MutableBoard` cannot see the `squares` array in `Board` because its private, and **subclasses do not inherit private fields** or methods. The code you have should not compile. The `squares` variable in the `MutableBoard` constructor is **not** the `squares` field in `Board`.

I suggest you change `squares` to be `protected` so subclasses can inherit it.

Comment: Don't think this is the issue. Sorry for the lack of info. Edited the post to make it more clear.